# intervation image wont store image in public path after i uploaded my laravel project on host

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i have a project that it has some posts on it
i have made admin panel to create new posts
since i uploaded my project on cpanel host i can create a post but image wont shown in my post but before that on my localhost i can craete a post and store image in my path
i checked my public path in my host and saw that there isn,t any new image related to my post that i have created with my admin panel on my host just my image name has saved in my database

this is my blog blade file

```
<section class="w-80 mx-auto my-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            @foreach($posts as $post)
                <div class="col-md-4 translate-box relative mb-4">
                    <div class="blog-box-height">
                        <a href="{{route('blog.single',['title'=>$post->title])}}"> <img src="{{asset('image/'.$post->header_image)}}" alt="{{$post->title}}" class="img-fluid"></a>
                        <div class="py-3 px-4">
                            <a class="text-xmedium fw-bold text-decoration-none text-black" href="{{route('blog.single',['title'=>$post->title])}}">
                                {{str_replace('_',' ',$post->title)}}
                            </a>
                            <p class="text-muted-1 mt-2 text-small">
                               {!! strip_tags(mb_substr($post->content,0,270,'utf-8')) !!} ...
                            </p>
                            <div class="box-time absolute">
                                <p class="text-muted-1"><i class="far fa-clock"></i> {{$post->time}} دقیقه</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

this is my postcontroller codes

```
public function storeImage(Request $request)
{
    $image_name = null;
    if ($request->file('image')) {
        $image = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $image_name = time() . $image;
        $folder = public_path('/image');
        $path = $folder . '/' . $image_name;

        if (is_dir($folder)) {
            $img = Image::make($request->file('image'))->resize(500, 438);
            $img->save($path);
        } else {
            File::makeDirectory($folder, 0755, true);
            $img = Image::make($request->file('image'))->resize(500, 438);
            $img->save($path);
        }
    }

    return $image_name;
}
```

this code works great in my localhost server but when i uploaded it on host i think image intervation wont work

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the symlink to connect the stroge folder with the public folder.
Try running `php artisan storage:link` on the webserver.

Also in some hostings this command is banned. In that case you have to create the symlink manually using forexample midnight commander.

Comment: i have done it but i doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try with 777 permission for make directory.

File::makeDirectory($folder, 0777, true);

Comment: this File::makeDirectory only works when i dont have folder that i want.so i have that folder in my public path i and changed the permission to 0755 but it didnt work because my folder is already exists and i think my problem is related to Image::make